# accessing values in jquery ajax multidimensional array

Tags: jquery

I know this has been asked a million times, but it's just not working for me. I have a PHP script (get_pathway_allowed.php) which outputs the following json format when hardcoded

```
{"pathway_allowed":"n","comment":"one comment"}{"pathway_allowed":"y","comment":"comment two"}{"pathway_allowed":"n","comment":"comment three"}{"pathway_allowed":"n","comment":"comment four"}
```

Ajax script:

```
$('.pathway_button').click(function() { 
alert(caseId + ' ' + currentLevel);
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "scripts/get_pathway_allowed.php",
       data: {case_id: caseId, level: currentLevel};
       dataType: "json",
       cache: false,
       success: function(response) {
            alert(response[0].pathway_allowed);

    }
});
});
```

Now `alert(caseId + ' ' + currentLevel);` shows the correct initial values of the two variables.  But I'm not seeing the alert after success.  If I remove `dataType: "json",` I see the success alert with values undefined (to be expected...).

get_pathway_allowed.php has:

```
$case = $_POST['case_id'];
$level = $_POST['level'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM pathway WHERE level = '$level' AND case_fk = '$case'";
$result = mysql_query($query, $connection) or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $caseData = array(
        'pathway_allowed' =>  $row['pathway_allowed'],
        'comment' =>  $row['comment']
        );

print json_encode($caseData);
}
```

As I said before, hardcoding:

```
$case = '10';
$level = '1';
```

outputs the json data as above OK.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the creation of the JSON-string is wrong, use:

```
$caseData=array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $caseData[] = array(
        'pathway_allowed' =>  $row['pathway_allowed'],
        'comment' =>  $row['comment']
        );

} 

print json_encode($caseData);
```

additionally there is a syntax-error:

```
data: {case_id: caseId, level: currentLevel};
//------------------------------------------^
```

the semicolon has to be a comma

Answer (score 1):

Fix your JSON String:

```
{ "values": [
    {"pathway_allowed":"n","comment":"one comment"},
    {"pathway_allowed":"y","comment":"comment two"},
    {"pathway_allowed":"n","comment":"comment three"},
    {"pathway_allowed":"n","comment":"comment four"}]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your json is not valid, it should look something like this:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "pathway_allowed": "n",
            "comment": "one comment"
        },
        {
            "pathway_allowed": "y",
            "comment": "comment two"
        },
        {
            "pathway_allowed": "n",
            "comment": "comment three"
        },
        {
            "pathway_allowed": "n",
            "comment": "comment four"
        }
    ]
}
```

use [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com) to validate your json.

Comment: I don't know php, but `print json_encode("{\"data\":[".$caseData."]}");` should fix the outer part, you also would need to add commas at the end of each rotation of the `while` loop except for the last.